# Is there a 4x4 unitary matrix with 0 diagonal and non-zero off-diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This question is homework from Scott Aaronson's 2017 [Quantum Information course](https://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=3943).

> a) Give an example of a 2x2 unitary matrix where the diagonal entries are 0 but the
>   off-diagonal entries are nonzero.
>
> b) Give an example for a 4x4 unitary matrix.
>
> c) Is it possible to have a 3x3 unitary matrix with this condition? If no, prove it!

(a) is easy.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

(c) is not possible. Since for

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a & b \\
c & 0 & d \\
e & f & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

to be unitary the inner product $0\cdot a + c \cdot 0 + e \cdot f$ needs to be zero, but then at least one of $e$ or $f$ needs to be 0.

For (b) I assume he means a 4x4 matrix where the diagonal elements are 0 but all other elements are non-zero (not just any unitary matrix).

I tried without luck:

- Building the 4x4 unitary matrix from 2x2 unitary block matrices. The closest I got so far is

  $$
  U = \begin{pmatrix}
  X & H \\
  H & -X
  \end{pmatrix}
    $$

  with

  $$
  X = \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 \\
  1 & -0
  \end{pmatrix}
    $$

  and

  $$
  H = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 \\
  1 & -1
  \end{pmatrix}
    $$

  Unfortunately $U^\dagger U$ leaves some non-diagonal elements.

  $$
    U^\dagger U = \begin{pmatrix}
  2 & 0 & \sqrt 2 & 0 \\
  0 & 2 & 0 & \sqrt 2 \\
  \sqrt 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
  0 & \sqrt 2 & 0 & 2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
   $$
- Starting with an arbitary first column and finding orthogonal column vectors with the desired 0 elements, but this seems tricky.

Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example:
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1  \\
1 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$